# C++ accessing multiple files with only one path known

Tags: c++, file

I am trying to make a simple text file compressor and de-compressor in C++.
So my compress program takes arguments from the user in cmd in this way:

```
compress abc.txt
```

Now what it does is, creates a compressed file, abc.cmp and a hidden info file, `info.cmp`.

while decompressing, it is supposed that both of these files are in the same directory.

Now my question is: if the file abc.cmp is not in the same directory as my decompress.exe, user is supposed to give the path of abc.cmp, but how will i use that path to access `info.cmp`?

For example user will only tpe:

```
decompress C:/abc.cmp
```

My program needs to access the info file as well but the user is not supposed to provide that path

```
 void readInfoFile(string &line, int &n, int &k, unsigned char * &cstream, int &count)
{
    ifstream fin("info.cmp");

    if (fin.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; !fin.eof(); i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
                fin >> n;
            else if (i == 1)
                fin >> k;
            else
            {
                getline(fin, line, '\0');
            }
        }
        fin.close();
    }
    for (int j = 1; line[j] != '\0'; j++)
    {
        line[j - 1] = line[j];
    }
    count = ceil((float)(((float)(k))/8));
    cstream = new unsigned char[count]();
}


    void compressedFileStore(unsigned char * &readingArray, int count, char*argv[])
{
    ifstream fin(argv[1], ios::in|ios::binary);
    fin.read((char*)readingArray, count);
    readingArray[count] = '\0';
    fin.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A file name cannot contain `/`, so you know that anything after the last `/` is the file name, and therefore, anything before and including the last `/` is the file path.

You can use a regular expression or another method to get the substring which is the path, append "info.cmp" to the end, and use that as the complete path.